# Como simular pressionar uma tecla por certo tempo?

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

Eu estava tentando fazer um BOT em Python que segurava a tecla z por 4 segundos e depois soltava, eu tentei usar o [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/), porém ao usar o `keyboard.press('z')`, o comando clicava apenas uma vez e não mantinha a tecla pressionada pelos 4 segundos.

Codigo:

```py
import pynput
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(2)
while True:
    keyboard.press('z')
    time.sleep(5)
    keyboard.release('z')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quando mantenho a tecla pressionada no teclado físico por diversas vezes é disparado um sinal para a tecla escolhida, ao menos é assim que os eventos na maioria das APIs que trabalham com "input" respondem de volta, por exemplo, em JavaScript ao colocar os eventos `document.onkeydown = e => console.log(e.key);` ou `document.onkeypress = e => console.log(e.key);` para ouvir as teclas será disparados diversos `console.log`, pode experimentar com seu teclado físico segurar a tecla <kbd>Z</kbd>:

```js
document.onkeypress = e => console.log(e.key);
```

Então em Python com pynput bastaria criar um `while` com o tempo desejado para manter isso rodando, no entanto ao testar com teclado físico aparentemente existe um delay enquanto se mantêm a tecla pressionada, eu não sei de quanto tempo é este delay, mas é provável que seja entre 0.04 segundos e 0.05 segundos, claro que isso é um tempo que eu sugeri, o tempo na verdade é definido pelo sistema operacional, exemplo no Windows 10 com taxa de repetição:

> [image: taxa de repetição do teclado no Windows 10]

Então baseado nessa [resposta que usa pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48683292/1518921) escrevi o código dessa forma:

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def hold_key(key, seconds):
    start = time.time()

    while time.time() - start < seconds:
        keyboard.press(key)
        time.sleep(0.047)

    keyboard.release(key)


keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(2)

while True:
    #pressiona por 5 segundos
    hold_key('z', 2)

    #espera 1 segundo para executar tecla A
    time.sleep(1)

    #pressiona por 4 segundos
    hold_key('a', 2)

    #espera 5 segundos para executar novamente
    time.sleep(5)
```

Note que é diferente do comportamento do .press do pyautogui, se for trocar o pyunpt por pyautogui então não vai precisar do `time.sleep(0.047)`, pode ser que o `keyboard.pressed()` resolveria, mas eu não tenho experiência com essa biblioteca, eu li a documentação, mas realmente não consegui aplicar.

Com pyautogui também não consegui resolver conforme a taxa de repetição do sistema operacional.

Talvez outra pessoa mais experiente possa sugerir uma resposta melhor no futuro com pynput.